# tidyverse purrr approach to adding elements to a list

Tags: r, tidyverse, purrr

I am looking for a `tidyverse` / `purrr` approach to adding elements to a list. For example:

```
library(tidyverse)

l <- list(c("a", "a", "b"), c("c", "d"), c("e", "f", "e", "g"))
l
[[1]]
[1] "a" "a" "b"

[[2]]
[1] "c" "d"

[[3]]
[1] "e" "f" "e" "g"
```

How can I build a pipeline `%>%` to return something like the following:

```
desired <- list(
  list(vec = c("a", "a", "b"), length = 3, unique = 2),
  list(vec = c("c", "d"), length = 2, unique = 2),
  list(vec = c("e", "f", "e", "g"), length = 4, unique = 3)
)

desired
[[1]]
[[1]]$vec
[1] "a" "a" "b"

[[1]]$length
[1] 3

[[1]]$unique
[1] 2


[[2]]
[[2]]$vec
[1] "c" "d"

[[2]]$length
[1] 2

[[2]]$unique
[1] 2


[[3]]
[[3]]$vec
[1] "e" "f" "e" "g"

[[3]]$length
[1] 4

[[3]]$unique
[1] 3
```

I know I can map individual functions using `l %>% map(length)` or `l %>% map(unique)`, but I would like to add new elements to the list and do this in one pipeline.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
l <- list(c("a", "a", "b"), c("c", "d"), c("e", "f", "e", "g"))
```

`Purr` approach:

```
l %>% 
  map(~ list(vec = .,
             length = length(.),
             unique = length(unique(.))))
```

Output

```
[[1]]
[[1]]$`vec`
[1] "a" "a" "b"

[[1]]$length
[1] 3

[[1]]$unique
[1] 2


[[2]]
[[2]]$`vec`
[1] "c" "d"

[[2]]$length
[1] 2

[[2]]$unique
[1] 2


[[3]]
[[3]]$`vec`
[1] "e" "f" "e" "g"

[[3]]$length
[1] 4

[[3]]$unique
[1] 3
```

However I would try to stick to using dataframes (tibbles) where possible:

```
l %>%
  tibble(vec = .) %>%
  mutate(length = map_dbl(vec, length),
         unique = map_dbl(vec, ~length(unique(.))))
```

Output:

```
# A tibble: 3 x 3
  vec       length unique
  <list>     <dbl>  <dbl>
1 <chr [3]>      3      2
2 <chr [2]>      2      2
3 <chr [4]>      4      3
```